# How to customize theme's semantic syntax highlighting in VS Code depending on language

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I'm using Electron theme in my VS Code and it works great, but the colors of text are different accross languages (I work with .vue .js .html .ts).

For example JS

```
'semicoloned string': green
"double quoted string": light-green
`template literals string`: white
```

meanwhile in TS everything is white, and for HTML the colors are completely different.

Is there a way how to extend this theme for the same color of syntax highlighting accross all languages I work with?

Comment: if the language server does not support semantic highlighting you get the default syntax highlighting